# npm installs modules to home directory

Tags: node.js, npm

Command of `npm install <module>` installs modules always user home directory not purposely. Which setting causes this behavior?
I simply want to install modules to the current path. If I try to install a module, in a folder that in the Desktop for instance, it installs to home directory.

```
mymac:testfolder myuser$ pwd
/Users/myuser/Desktop/untitledfolder
mymac:testfolder myuser$ npm install async
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
async@2.1.4 ../../node_modules/async
└── lodash@4.17.4
```

as you see, it installs the modules to `../../node_modules/`. I do not have package.json file in testfolder.

Comment: What does `npm root` print?

Comment: it gives /Users/myuser/node_modules

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have package.json in you current directory.

Did you run `npm init`?

If you don't have package.json in your current directory then it may try find it in the upper directory, find in your home and install modules there.

Comment: I think this is the problem. after I init npm, it creates package.json and install node_modules in current folder. thanks

Comment: I am having the same problem and running npm init solves this for me as well. However I am pretty sure that previously I could just run npm install <package> and it would simply install the package in the current directory, no mater whether there is a package.json or not.